# Basic html/ css issue?

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to work out this issue, I have created a basic page with a couple heading tags. Here is the problem:

My H1 tag is working fine it is INSIDE the red container BUT the H2 tag seems to be outside it????

I cant work out what Im doing wrong? HELP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST2</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:900px; height:100px; margin:0 auto; border: 2px solid red;">

        <h1>Hello World</h1>

        <h2 style="float:right;">Hello World 2</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF CONTAINER -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden;` to the container - your `<h2>` is taken out of the normal flow because it's floated.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: How *do* you want it to lay out?

Comment: or set the style of h1 to `float:left`

Comment: inline styles are a bad practice, have a separate CSS file with your styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow this demo: http://jsbin.com/epOHaPa/1 in-which we set `display: inline-block` for both headings and assignig `width` for the `h1`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST2</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:900px; height:100px; margin:0 auto; border: 2px solid red;">

      <h1 style="display:inline-block; width:300px;">Hello World</h1>

      <h2 style="float:right; display:inline-block">Hello World 2</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF CONTAINER -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a set height for the container div.  The `<h1>` creates a new block formatting context so the `h2` appears below it even though it is floated.  To fix this, put the `h2` *before* the `h1`.

http://jsfiddle.net/YpDzb/

Semantically that does not make sense, though.  You can keep the content order if you also float the `h1`

http://jsfiddle.net/YpDzb/1/